# Angular 1.5 component inside ng-repeat, template function run just once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive, angular-components

I tried to use angular component replacing directive for creating component (a data table).
I want to use the component inside of ng-repeat like:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
<my-datatable></my-datatable>
</div>
```

The my-datatable component code look like this:

```
 angular.module('App').component('myDatatable', {
        bindings: {
            ctrl: '=?',
            datasource: '=?'
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'dataTable',
        template: function(){},
        controller: function(){}
    });
```

First problem:
1. template function is not runnig for every instance of my-datatable component. 
That mean, if inside my-datatable I have other components generated based by an unique Id of my-datatable (which can be create only in controller), it's difficult to write that code.
2. The nested isolate scope, create o much too long chains of $parent, for make a reference to some scope variable, something like this (if I use two nested my-datatable's):

```
 ng-click="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.select($parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.dataItem,dataItem)"
```

So, my question is:
It is a way to avoid this problems using angular component?

Writing controls code with directive without isolate scope, I don't have this problems. That why I want to change my code for all angular components as directives.

I start to change may component into directive, and I remember few things:

- For long chains of $parent.$parent..., I create in component controller a variable $parent with reference for parent scope of component, so if I need a reference inside component to outside scope, I can use: dataTable.$parent.
- The good thing for isolate scope, it's I can destroy component and recreate, very simple and clean ( all the watchers are removed when I destroyed the isolate scope), which is not possible with directive way with no isolate scope.

That mean,it remain only the problem to generate unique id for each component instance in template function. **In other words: how to run template function on each instance of component.**

For exemplify:
https://jsfiddle.net/bogdanim36/t3gmzb6z/3/

And made some tests and I discover that it's happen the same with directive inside ng-repeat: template function is not running for every instance of component.

Comment: How do you know the template function is not running for every instance?

Comment: I put  a console.log() in template and controller functions, to trace it. It's was a real unpleasant surprise for me, this behavior.

Comment: provide a fiddle to reproduce the problem

Comment: In my mind, you are misusing components. The base of a good component is that it is a full isolated part, means, it should not be dependent on his container, once you are using `$parent` everywhere, you create a very strong coupling. If you want to pass data / events between components, use a service, callbacks binding or the events system (`$broadcast`, `$emit` and `$on`).

Comment: I do have events declared on my component and factory, but the problem apear when I have a tree structure : datatables in datatables.. in datatables. But I found solution to reference the controller view scope, creating a variable in component controller named rootScope (dataTable.$rootScope, and dataTable.$parent)

Comment: Another problem: in my component I use custom templates for different parts of datatable (columns, headers, filters,etc), which must be easy to implement, that why is much simple to write some methods in controller view, which can be fired in any datatable at any level of tree

Answer (score 0):

Finally I generate html code in controller, to solve this issue, That mean one more digest cycle. Is not what I want, but i decided it's the best solution in my case.